# How to export gridview to excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am having problem with the code I wrote for exporting datagridview to excel on button_click event.
The error

> cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'

shows at this line of code

```
new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application();
```

the object library in the reference is microsoft excel 14.0 object libary . I am using VS Ultimate 2013. The Ms Office is 2010

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet Worksheet = null;
Worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
Worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
Worksheet.Name = "StudentDetail";
for (int i=1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count+1; i++ )
{
    Worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}
for (int i=0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++ )
{
  for (int j=1; j <dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++ )
  {
      Worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
  }

}
var saveFileDialogue = new SaveFileDialog();
saveFileDialogue.FileName = "Output";
saveFileDialogue.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
if(saveFileDialogue.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
{
    workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialogue.FileName, Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing);
}
app.Quit();
```

I expect to successully export datagrivew to excel.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the **class [`Excel.Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.application?view=excel-pia)**.

You are trying to instantiate the interface [`Excel._Application`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application?view=excel-pia) which is not possible.

Comment: Thank you Peter the error has been resolved but noticed another error at this line of code:  Worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();    The error is:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: To change the contents of a cell you'd have to use something like this: `Worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Value = .....`

Comment: I have done that but the error persists.  This is how I did it:                    Worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();